# reshaping a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently trying to reshape a matrix of images which is of size 10304*80. I am trying to take the first 5 columns of the matrix giving me 10304*5 and reshape it to (112*92,5). This is my attempt but I keep getting the value error cannot reshape array of size 20608 into shape (10304,5). Any advice on how to do this?

```
test_PC_first5 = test_PC[:, [1,5]]
test_PC_first5 = test_PC_first5.reshape(112*92,5)
plt.plot(test_PC_first5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what your code is doing is taking colums 1 and 5 only thats why you have a shape of 20608 which is 2*10304. you need to edit your first line to

```
test_PC_first5 = test_PC[:, 0:5]
```

in order to keep the first 5 lines. keep in mind index starts at 0 not 1

Comment: Ah that fixed everything can I ask how you would do it for the last 5 columns I have been trying to do it with Test_PC_last5 = test_PC[: [-5:] which is actually giving me a runtime error.

Comment: @JoeyHoward988 yeah sure you just do test_PC_first5 = test_PC[:, -5:]  , don't forget since it was the answer you needed to accept it as the correct